# Easy Riddles #4: What ocean creature am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am an animal that lives in the ocean,
>
> I move very fast using a strange kind of motion.
>
> You will never see me in any one group
>
> Poem written by...Anatomic Soup

**What am I?**

*This riddle isn't hard, but I'd like an explanation for every line please :))*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hmm, 2 hours and no attempts by anyone else.  So let me break my decision not to post the answer.

> I am an octopus.

I am an animal that lives in the ocean

> Octopi live in the oceans

I move very fast using a strange kind of motion.

> Octopi propel themselves using a stream of water ejected at speed

You will never see me in any one group

> Octopi don't move in groups, they swim independently.  They only hook up when, erm, hooking up! (I needed Wikipedia to confirm this)

Poem written by...Anatomic Soup

> The poet's name is a  anagram for the answer: I am an octopus.
>  (Mmm, soup).